# Why would you execute $q.when() without passing it a promise/value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, q

According to [the Angular docs on $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), $q.when() expects a promise/value to passed in.

But I just came across someone else's code where it's called without passing in any params. Here's a simplified version of what I see:

```
var modal = false;

if (modalOpen) {
    return $q.when()
}
modalOpen = true;

modal = newModal({
    template: opts.template,
});

modal.result.finally(function(){ 
    modalOpen = false;
});
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Methods should either return synchronously or return asynchronously to remain consistent. If a method returns synchronously sometimes and still wants to keep the fact sometimes it is already resolved transparent - it returns an empty resolved promise. Having APIs that sometimes return promises and sometimes synchronously is a [recipe for trouble](http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony).

Using `$q.when` is the simplest way to get an empty resolved promise in Angular.

Comment: Glad I could help. It's worth mentioning that the error case is also true - Promise returning methods should not `throw` synchronously but rather return rejections.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wondering what `$q.when()` **returns** - it returns **`undefined`**.

If you need it to return `null`, then do `$q.when(null)`.

This is useful when you have a type system like TypeScript and need to know what the return type is for your method when you're unable to resolve the promise with the type requested.

```
const getUser = async (id: number): Promise<User | undefined> =>
    someCondition ? Api.getUser(id) : $q.when();
```